# Please Verify the htaccess code

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, web

I have a URL like this

```
http://www.freshupnow.com/movie.php?moviename=A+Flat
```

I want to rewrite this URL using .htaccess code like this

```
http://www.freshupnow.com/movies/A+Flat
```

So, I have used the following code for this

```
RewriteRule ^movies/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ movie.php?moviename=$1 [NC,L]
```

Can Some one please verify it, Either it is Right or Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([A-Za-z0-9-]+) should be ([A-Za-z0-9+])+ coz you want to capture the whole group 1 or more times and you also want to allow "+" character in your movie names, as in the example "A+Flat". You can validate your regex yourself using this online tool: [Regex Validate](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/). There are several others, try Googling for it.